# Obtener el id de una url amigable

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Saludo. estoy intentando obtener solo el `ID` de una url y no logro obtenerlo. Y otro problema que descubi, es que no puedo volver a `inicio` desde `produsto/13`.

Directorio

```
urlAmigable
    |_ pages
    |    |_ producto.php
    |    |_ default.php
    |_ index.php
    |_ .htaccess
```

index.php

```
echo '<a href="default">Inicio</a><br>';
echo '<a href="producto/13">Producto</a><br>';

if($_GET){
    $url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
    require_once 'pages/'.$url[0].'.php';
}
```

producto.php

```
$idProducto = $_GET['url'];

echo 'El id del producto es: '.$idProducto;

// resultado: producto/13
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto:

`RewriteRule ^nuevoNombre/([^/]+)*$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`
#después llamas a la url así: "`nuevoNombre/`" y le agregas lo demás en tu archivo php

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: También en tu `if` agrega esto `isset($_GET['url'])` para evitar problemas, es solo un recomendación.